# Debugging exceptions in a Async/Await (Call Stack)

Tags: c#, stack-trace, async-await, visual-studio-debugging, c#-5.0

I use the Async/Await to free my UI-Thread and accomplish multithreading. Now I have a problem when I hit a exception. The `Call Stack` of my Async parts allways starts with `ThreadPoolWorkQue.Dipatch()`, which doesn't help me very much.

I found a MSDN-Article [Andrew Stasyuk. Async Causality Chain Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891052.aspx) about it but as I understand it, its not a ready to use solution.

What is the best/easiest way to debug if you use multithreading with Async/Await?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The article you found does a good job of explaining why call stacks don't work the way most of us think they do. Technically, the call stack only tells us where the code is returning to after the current method. In other words, the call stack is "where the code is going", not "where the code came from".

Interestingly, the article does mention a solution in passing, but doesn't expound on it. I have [a blog post that goes explains the `CallContext` solution in detail](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). Essentially, you use the logical call context to create your own "diagnostic context".

I like the `CallContext` solution better than the solution presented in the article because it does work will all forms of `async` code (including fork/join code like `Task.WhenAll`).

This is the best solution I know of (other than doing something really complex like hooking into the profiling API). Caveats of the `CallContext` approach:

- It only works on .NET 4.5 full. No support for Windows Store apps, .NET 4.0, etc.
- You do have to "instrument" your code manually. There's no way AFAIK to inject it automatically.
- Exceptions don't capture the logical call context automatically. So this solution works fine if you're breaking into the debugger when exceptions are thrown, but it's not as useful if you're just catching the exceptions in another place and logging them.

The code (depends on the [immutable collections NuGet library](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable)):

```
public static class MyStack
{
    private static readonly string name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

    private static ImmutableStack<string> CurrentContext
    {
        get
        {
            var ret = CallContext.LogicalGetData(name) as ImmutableStack<string>;
            return ret ?? ImmutableStack.Create<string>();
        }

        set
        {
            CallContext.LogicalSetData(name, value);
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable Push([CallerMemberName] string context = "")
    {
        CurrentContext = CurrentContext.Push(context);
        return new PopWhenDisposed();
    }

    private static void Pop()
    {
        CurrentContext = CurrentContext.Pop();
    }

    private sealed class PopWhenDisposed : IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposed;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (disposed)
                return;
            Pop();
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    // Keep this in your watch window.
    public static string CurrentStack
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(" ", CurrentContext.Reverse());
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static async Task SomeWorkAsync()
{
    using (MyStack.Push()) // Pushes "SomeWorkAsync"
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Update:** I released a [NuGet package (described on my blog)](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/announcement-async-diagnostics.html) that uses PostSharp to inject the pushes and pops automatically. So getting a good trace should be a lot simpler now.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I'll try and see how it works :-). I was somehow hoping there would be a solution like `Paralell Stack`with more information. But you can't have everything ;-). Am I correct that only `MyStack.Push()` logs and I need it everywhere if I want to know where I've been?

Comment: `MyStack.Push` and `MyStack.Pop` (the disposal) modify the stack, and yes, you need to add them everywhere. :(  VS2012 is the first release supporting `async`; hopefully we will get better debugging support in the future!

Comment: You saved my day. Knowing where one came from realy makes a difference in debugging ^^. Bugs I've been searching for days became clear almost instantly; Its just too bad I can't find your blog entry with google without using your name. Maybe you might want to goolge optimize because your blog is good and has other useful entries I will read when I find the time.

Comment: Glad I could help! It's true my blog is not SEO'd at all, and I should really do that...

Comment: Update: I released a [NuGet package (described on my blog)](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/announcement-async-diagnostics.html) that uses PostSharp to inject the pushes and pops automatically. So getting a good trace should be a lot simpler now.